# SSIS - last day of month from an input date

Tags: date, ssis, flat-file

I have a package that receives a date field from a flat file. Is there any quick transform this date to the last date of the same month?

e.g.
Input: 01.08.2019
Output: 31.08.2019

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is via `Lookup`.

Package -

[image]

So, basically you read the file then pass on them to `Lookup` which would run for each of them and query in the database to find out the last day of the month for the input date.

You need `OLEDB` connection to be setup for the database queries and below `SQL` query would do the job for you -

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(10) = ?
SET @date = REPLACE(@date,'.','/');
SET @date = CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@date,10),105),101);
SET @date = EOMONTH(@date);
SET @date = SUBSTRING(@date, 9, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@date, 6, 2)  + '/' + SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4);
SELECT REPLACE(@date,'/','.') AS Result;
```

Answer (score 3):

i use this one a lot:

Substitute @d for your date column.

```
dateadd("d",-1, --Gets last day of current month
  dateadd("mm",1, --Gets 1st day of next month
    (DT_DATE)(month(@d) + "/1/" + year(@d)) -- Gets first day of current month
))
```

Comment: You might need a few casts for month and year to strings

Comment: In the absence of a date table this is the next best solution that I am aware of - add one month and then subtract one day.